# How can I parse the content of file to variables?

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

I have text file which looks like this :

> ABC=-1 Temp=2 Try=34 Message="some text" SYS=3
>   ABC=-1 Temp=5 Try=40 Message="some more and different text" SYS=6

and the pattern continues but only the numeric values and text inside the " " is changed.

**NOTE**: the **Message=** could have **multiple quotes** as well.

I want to store the value of **ABC,Temp,Try and SYS** to **int variables**
And **Message** to a **String variable**.

I am currently using:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  int count = line.indexOf("ABC=");
  if (count >= 0) {
    int clear = line.charAt(count + 3);
  }
}
scanner.close();
```

I thought of using the **Scanner class** and read line by line, but I am confused about how can I classify the line in different variables?

Comment: Read a line, split using `"\\s+"`, then split each array element using `"="` and then check if what the element on index 0 is and assign it accordingly.

Comment: wanna post some code and show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Tom He has a string, which might contain white spaces.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I posted some code but that is not correct.

Comment: @Tom If I split them in terms of space, then my message would be split into many tokens.

Comment: @Rakesh yes you are right, do you have something to go about this problem?

Comment: @XOR Splitting on " " is a straight forward method if you are ready to do some array manipulations to join the `message` part of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make a class that represents the data:

```
public static class MyData { // please pick a better name
    final int abc;
    final int temp;
    final int tryNumber; // try is a keyword
    final String message;
    final int sys;

    public MyData(int abc, int temp, int tryNumber, String message, int sys) {
      this.abc = abc;
      this.temp = temp;
      this.tryNumber = tryNumber;
      this.message = message;
      this.sys = sys;
    }
}
```

Then make a method that transforms a `String` into this class using [Regex capture groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
private static Pattern p =
  Pattern.compile("ABC=([^ ]+) Temp=([^ ]+) Try=([^ ]+) Message=\"(.+)\" SYS=([^ ]+)");

private static MyData makeData(String input) {
  int abc = 0, temp = 0, tryNumber = 0, sys = 0;
  String message = "";

  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  if (!(m.find()) return null;
  abc = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
  temp = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
  tryNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
  message = m.group(4);
  sys = Integer.parseInt(m.group(5));

  return new MyData(abc, temp, tryNumber, message, sys);
}
```

Then read the file using a scanner:

```
public static void main (String... args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.txt");
    List<MyData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        MyData data = makeData(line);
        if(data != null) dataList.add(data);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

[Here's a completely working demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/lLFLuH)

Comment: I am afraid the message would be overwritten in makeData, and wont be able to contain the full message string.

Comment: You've tested it? With the unknown variable `file` in `new Scanner(file);` and with your `static` constructor in the `MyData` class? :P

Comment: @XOR I hope you use this answer and not the others because the others just print to the console and don't preserve the data in any sort of usable form.

Comment: Keep in mind that your pattern of "[^ ]+" will allow alphanumeric data which will fail with Integer.parseInt()

Comment: @durron597 Thats more a sophisticated approach. Thanks
I will try for sure.

Comment: @durron597 If my Message is like this : " some messaege "text" some more message" will this case work?

Comment: @XOR All three answers will work for nested quotes now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` for this kind of parsing with a pattern of:

```
"ABC=([+-]?\\d+) Temp=([+-]?\\d+) Try=([+-]?\\d+) Message=\"(.+)\" SYS=([+-]?\\d+)"
```

Pattern Breakdown ([Pattern Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

- `ABC=` - literal string
- `([+-]?\\d+)` - captures a positive or negative number in capture group 1
- `Temp=` - literal string
- `([+-]?\\d+)` - captures a positive or negative number in capture group 2
- `Try=` - literal string
- `([+-]?\\d+)` - captures a positive or negative number in capture group 3
- `Message=` - literal string
- `\"(.+)\"` captures a string in between double quotes in capture group 4
- `SYS=` - literal string
- `([+-]?\\d+)` - captures a positive or negative number in capture group 5

If the `String` matches the pattern you can extract your values like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList() {{
        add("ABC=-1 Temp=2 Try=34 Message=\"some text\" SYS=3");
        add("ABC=-1 Temp=5 Try=40 Message=\"some more \"and\" different text\" SYS=6");
    }};
    String pattern = "ABC=([+-]?\\d+) Temp=([+-]?\\d+) Try=([+-]?\\d+) Message=\"(.+)\" SYS=([+-]?\\d+)";

    int abc = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int tryNum = 0;
    String message = "";
    int sys = 0;
    for (String d : data) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(d);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            abc = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            temp = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            tryNum = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            message = matcher.group(4);
            sys = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5));

            System.out.printf("%d %d %d %s %d%n", abc, temp, tryNum, message, sys);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
-1 2 34 some text 3
-1 5 40 some more "and" different text 6
```

Comment: @durron597 I realized that, I'm just lazy with using "\r\n" or "\n" as part of the format. :-P

Comment: that's what `%n` is for

Comment: @Shar1er80 If my Message is like this : " some messaege "text" some more message"
will this case work?

Comment: @XOR No, it will not work.  I've updated my answer to account for that case.

Comment: @Shar1er80 Could you explain the change?

Comment: @XOR Bullet 8 of the pattern breakdown explains that your are capturing any character (That's what the period means in regex) one or more times (The plus sign).  I also added a URL to reference for regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using the `indexOf` approach, the following code will work

```
    String a = "ABC=-1 Temp=2 Try=34 Message=\"some text\" SYS=3";
    int abc_index = a.indexOf("ABC");
    int temp_index = a.indexOf("Temp");
    int try_index = a.indexOf("Try");
    int message_index = a.indexOf("Message");
    int sys_index = a.indexOf("SYS");
    int length = a.length();

    int abc = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(abc_index + 4, temp_index - 1));
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(temp_index + 5, try_index - 1));
    int try_ = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(try_index + 4, message_index - 1));
    String message = a.substring(message_index + 9, sys_index - 2);
    int sys = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(sys_index + 4, length));

    System.out.println("abc : " + abc);
    System.out.println("temp : " + temp);
    System.out.println("try : " + try_);
    System.out.println("message : " + message);
    System.out.println("sys : " + sys);
```

This will give you the following

```
abc : -1
temp : 2
try : 34
message : some text
sys : 3
```

This will work only if the string data you get has this exact syntax, ie, it contains `ABC`, `Temp`, `Try`, `Message`, and `SYS`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I had this in mind, but I wanted some what more sophisticated answer, though Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @XOR I found the that the solution provided by Shar1er80 is much more elegant. I would suggest you use that approach to get the values, and use POJO classes like durron597 suggests.

Comment: @durron597 oh, sorry. I had read yours when it was splitting on space. My bad.